# how to run unsafe-inline in a web page, not in chrome extension page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, mouseclick-event, content-pages

the web page code is here:

```
<a id="pagerBottomNew_nextButton" title="下一页" class="Search_page-cut" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pagerBottomNew$nextButton','')"><i class="Common_icon Common_icon_caret_right_large"></i></a>
```

ny content page code is here:

```
   let event = new MouseEvent("click", { "bubbles": true, "cancelable": true });
   let ele = document.querySelector(request.args.target);
   if (ele != null) ele.dispatchEvent(event);
   sendResponse({ type: 'done' });
```

when execute the

```
ele.dispatchEvent(event);
```

chrome report the message:

**Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.**

the web page is from a commercial web site, how to simulate the click event without breaking the CSP.

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, which you can report on https://crbug.com. The workaround is to dispatch the event in [page context](/a/9517879).

Comment: @wOxxOm can I add the ele.click() in method 4

Answer (score 0):

to fix your problem, use this:

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
 }
```

The "style-src" part, might not need, but it's helpful. for more information [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy).

Answer (score 0):

LeonTM's answer is literally correct, but you should not do this (unless you really know what you are doing) as enabling `'unsafe-inline'` will allow injection attacks.

I'd recommend people to read [this article](https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-inline/) before enabling this.